# 74HC595 sinking, not sourcing

Tags: arduino, shift-register, 74hc595

I'm trying to get an [SN74HC595N](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/sn74hc595) working with an Arduino Due. Eventually I will be hooking up each output to an NPN transistor to drive Nixie tubes (I am switching my design from a Due to using an ESP8266, so I need to cut back on the pin use, hence the shift register).

I have been using [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-4-eight-leds/breadboard-layout) as the schematic to get working (except using 3.3 V instead of 5 V since I'm using a Due).

When set up according to the schematic nothing works (I'm using the same code too), however, when reversing the polarity of the LEDs and hooking them up to high, it works, so the 74HC595 is working fine as a sink, but it doesn't seem to be sourcing.

Am I missing something to make it source?

Here is what I have set up (currently only using 1 LED just to make sure things work):

[image]

And here is it set up with the 74HC595 as a source (which is not currently working):

[image]

Comment: make a single channel schematic

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I'm not familiar with what a single channel schematic is (unless it's just a normal schematic like you'd make in altium)

Comment: using the lame circuit editor herer or ASCII dwg here to show the CMOS driver supply voltages, LED, ,NPN , nixie tube and  when/where your fault is.. something clearer than your explanation

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Ok post updated with schematic, and what I am trying to set up

Comment: That will work fine. You need to look at the data sheet from TI, and it lists the output voltage in both source and sink modes for different currents. Go do some research.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast From the data sheet, it says the output voltage in source mode will be Vcc with a max current of 35mA (the led resistor set  up will draw 3.3V at 3.3mA so that should be a non issue), in sink it can sink up to 35mA

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your schematic. There is therefore something wrong with your implementation or the parts you are using or the firmware that's controlling it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany correct me if I'm wrong, but if it's working as a sink, the only thing that should change to make it source is reverse the diode and connect it to ground instead of 3V3

Comment: @soup Yes, plus of course write a 1 to turn it on rather than a 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## It looks like we’ve encountered some resistance.

[image]

The Pch and Nch have a wide tolerance for Vt near 1.25V and if the Vt of Pch is higher than the Nch this would explain the inability to drive the LED.

Although rated for 2~6V for the 74HC' CMOS family, the worst case specs for (Vdd-Voh) match Vol so it is the symmetrical worst case but typically, one may expect slightly weaker Pch or higher Vt thresholds.
[image]
However the guaranteed IC std. test currents are as follows;
at **2V** @ 25'C,  Vol/Iol = 0.1V/20uA **= 5k Ω** = Ron " RdsOn "
at **4.5V** @ 25'C,  Vol/Iol = 0.26V/4mA **= 65 Ω**
at **6.0V**  @ 25'C,  Vol/Iol = 0.26V/7.8mA **= 33 Ω**
Thus interpolating to 3.3V I expect RdsOn may 400~500 Ohms [image] is wishful thinking.

**Conclusion:**

For your prototype, you can bypass the 1K resistor.

For reliable LED driving 3.3V RdsOn performance, you can switch to the 74VHC' CMOS family **74VHC595 which is 360mV/4mA= 90 Ohms** @ Vdd=3.0V

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm going to order some 74VHC595's and see if that works instead. I tried bypassing the 1K resistor, however the LED still can't be driven.

Comment: What voltage is across LED? 1.6?  I assume you cannot invert the signal in Duo?

Comment: As a sink 1.7V (while using the 1K resistor). As a source with the 1K resistor, 56mV (but not changing when it should be set high).Without the 1K, 92mV again not changing even when set high. When I probe the pin voltage when it's set up as a source, it never registers at 3.3V relative to ground.

Comment: One other question, If I understand correctly, the issue is that the internal resistance is too high, so I don't have the necissary voltage to drive the LED, however I would expect there to still be some voltage to ground. When I replace the LED and 1K resistor with a voltmeter then, the reading should be about 3.3V since the voltmeter has a much higher resistance, however the voltmeter in this case still reads 0V (actually about 3mV when sent a 0 and 0mV when sent a 1).

Comment: if Vgs(th) = Vd=2V it can only conduct about 20uA ( and typical Vgs(th)=Vt tests are 100uA) so these newer parts have a lower threshold.(towards each rail)  and can operate  at slightly lower Vdd's than 74HC's so at 3.3V they can guarantee adequate current for your drive

Comment: You see when the Vdd ratings go lower, Vt must be lower and RdsOn must also be low, but if you exceed the Vdd rating when both FETs are ON at he same time during transition they draw excess current. from cross conduction.  Unlike Half bridges, CMOS logic has no deadband and always operates conducting on both FETs during transition, which is why they use a decoupling cap on each IC when TTL only needed 1 per 10 IC's

Comment: Got the 74VHC595, everything is working well now, thanks!

Comment: YW  works as expected

Comment: CMOS logic drives like all FETs obey Ohms Law  if you have at least 1.5x the threshold voltage for low V types and 2.5x times for  4V type Vgs(th) FETs  So I use Vol/Iol typ and max to compute at each Vdd, but I found this P/N not from experience but searching for one CMOS family that supported <2V and 5.5V